# Yii2 - How to get field value from relation

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I have a table which has different types of text data from different sources, identified by type, lang, sourceId and stored in field `text`. Is there anyway to return by active record relation not object of table but only value of field `text` in oher words scalar query via relation?

Example: For now I have:

```
$modelName->RelationName->text) //field name storing expexted data, returns string.
```

Desired way is:

```
$modelName->RelationName//text field value returned only.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes But using `lazy loading` approach :

Update Your Relation as

```
public function getRelationName(){
    //Related model Class Name
    //related column name as select
    return $this->hasOne(RelationClass::className() ,['id' => 'id'])->select('name')->scalar();
}
```

then get relation value as : -

```
$modelName->relationName//text field value returned only.
```

Comment: Ok, in current state it breaks with condition.

Comment: as I have told `eager loading` get failed

Comment: Of course I can make overload for __getMethod for current active record ... does it realy framework dont allows to make it in more beatiful way?

Comment: works fine `_get` magic method but your getter method will no longer call.

Answer (score 1):

Extend your model with one or more  getter for retrive the value you need using a relation  eg:

In the model you need retrive the related data you can build a funtion for define the raltion (in this case an hasOne)

```
 */
public function getRelationName()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ModelOfTheRelation::className(), ['column1' => 'column1', 'EvColumn2' => 'Evcolumn2']);
}
```

Then you can use getter function for the data

```
/* Getter f */
public function getRelatioName_field() 
{
    return $this->relationName->field;
}
```

In view  you can easy obtain the data using

```
echo $model->relationName_field

or in gridview (dataprovider)


 'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'relationName_field',
```

this link could be useful http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/